# Angular2 Rxjs Observable catch method compilation error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This line of typescript code is throwing an error when transpiling.

```
  getXXX(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('api/xxx').catch(err => {return err});
  }
```

The error is

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

I have the following imports in my script

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

How doI fix it

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis `)`. Also, you can just import `Observable` instead of the whole lib: `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
`

Comment: Corrected my question, the new import did not help

Comment: What you have is not a valid error handler in any case. Don't catch errors in parts of your program with insufficient context to handle them. Returning error is invalid. Remove the catch.

Answer (score 1):

this is syntax error for Typescript. When `arrow function` has `{}`, in `{}` there must have a `return`, **[relevant link](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_arrow-function-syntax)**.

```
this.http.get('api/xxx').catch(err => { return err; });
```

or simply not use `{}`

```
this.http.get('api/xxx').catch(err => err);
```

Comment: I still have the same error after making suggested changes

Comment: @Sridhar can you post the entire function where you called `this.http.get`?

Comment: @Sridhar or else, are you setting any other parameters to `this.http.get`?

Comment: @Sridhar mm.... your code looks fine this time. are you sure the error is on this `http.get` line?